# How do I mock find method in laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, mocking, phpunit

I am trying to write a unit test, and I need to be able to mock an internal call to App::make('ClassName')->find($x). However, when I try this:

```
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ClassName')->
        setMethods(['find'])->
        getMock();
    $mock->method('find')->willReturn('test');
    echo $mock->find(1);
```

I get a `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_BadMethodCallException` with no message describing the error. Looking ad xdebug trace, I see that it calls the mock::find method, then immediately calls spl_autoload_call to get the BadMethodCallException class.

Why is the find method failing? If I use a different method (e.g. `findx`), then it works perfectly. What is magic about `find`, and how can I fix it?

Comment: you can use Mockery ...it's so easy for mocking.